# Eclipse semicolon inserted before cursor when typing full line not using content assist

Tags: eclipse

This behavior is dring me batty.

I type the following:

`fileName.append(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))`

Now when I typed that the content assist poped up.  I did not pick HOUR_OF_DAY from the content assist nor did I press enter to fill it in automatically.  I just typed "HOUR_OF_DAY".  I typed both end parens ")" at the end of line too, I did not press tab.

My cursor is now at the end of the line and I type ;

Eclipse inserts the ; AFTER the cursor!  So when I press enter, the semicolon moves to the next line!

I've tried everything I can think of in the preferences. I turned on "auto smeicolon" option that is supposed to place semicolons at the end of the line automatically but it doesn't fix this.

One clue: if I press "ENTER" before typing ";" at the end of the line, the content assist window goes away and the ; is inserted properly with the cursor now afte the ;.  So content assist is messing with me.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ESC key drops the content assist menu.

Comment: So that doesn't explain why the content assist menu would cause the ; to be placed after the cursor.  It should just dismiss it's self or at least do no harm.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Typing and uncheck Semicolons in the Automatically insert at correct position group.

Comment: so: "I've tried everything I can think of in the preferences. I turned on "auto smeicolon" option that is supposed to place semicolons at the end of the line automatically but it doesn't fix this."

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I just started seeing this exact behavior after changing some of my preferences, I switched them back and the behavior went back to normal.

Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist:

[image: Auto Activation Settings]

These settings are the default and do not produce the bad behavior you describe.

When I was seeing the unwanted behavior, I had the delay set to 50ms and the auto activation triggers set to "`.(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`"