# Eclipse Java IDE, Inserting a semi colon gets placed after the cursor. How do I fix it?

Tags: java, eclipse

Right now when I insert a semi colon after something like:

Scanner(System.in);, it puts my cursor in-between the colon and the end parenthesis like this:

Scanner(System.in)|;

How do I get it to put my cursor here:

Scanner(System.in);|

I tried looking at this help link but it's out of date and the ones that do work don't work.
[Eclipse semicolon inserted before cursor when typing full line not using content assist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669306/eclipse-semicolon-inserted-before-cursor-when-typing-full-line-not-using-content#3670595)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Editor --> Content Assist; inside the box "Auto Activation", I unchecked "Enable auto activation." That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.
Go to window - > Preferences - > Restore Defaults

Comment: I think I may have figured it out however I'm not sure if it could negatively affect me in the future. Under ...Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist, I unchecked "Enable auto activation." That fixed it, however I'm somewhat concerned that could create a problem later or is there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem(it was driving me crazy!)

Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist:
set the delay to 200 or more,then the cursor will act like the way you wanted.